# My Installer is detected as virus because of Inetc.dll

Tags: nsis

After checking the code of inetc.dll, I see that the call to win32 wininet HttpOpenRequest is triggering a HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Generic. I'm using inetc to download a part of the installation based on the user's os config to allow a smaller installer. Are there any way to avoid this false positives? Are there any other alternatives to inetc that don't get flagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to see false positives for both INetC and NSISdl, report it as a false positive and the problem should go away...